# How do I turn the fucntion sumVec into a template function

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I got this code (I know it's in Spanish I can translate if needed) where they give me the function SumVec. What the function does is it receives as parameters two arrays (integer pointers) and an integer (size) and returns a pointer to the sum of the two vectors or arrays. I have to convert it so it can receive any type, not just integer. I know that you do that with a template by using "template " but I've only done simple classes I don't know how to do it with pointers. Any help?

The code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int * sumVec(int*, int*, int);
int main() {
int n, nCol, nFil = 0;
//Arreglo unidimensional din�mico
int *ptr, *suma, size;
cout << "Cuantos Items va a procesar:";
cin >> size;
ptr = new int[size];//Asignando memoria al arreglo
//input
for (int i = 0;i<size;i++) {
cout << "Ingrese el numero de Items NO." << i + 1 << " :";
cin >> ptr[i];
}
//Mostrando el contenido del archivo
for (int i = 0;i<size;i++) cout << "\nItem. NO." << i + 1 << " :" << ptr[i];
cout << endl;

suma = sumVec(ptr, ptr, size);

//Mostrando el contenido de la suma
for (int i = 0;i<size;i++) cout << "\nSuma Item. NO." << i + 1 << " :" << suma[i];
cout << endl;

delete[]ptr;//Liberando la memoria asignada al arreglo unidimensional.

return 0;
}
int * sumVec(int* Array1, int* Array2, int Size){
  int *ptr = new int[Size];
  for(int i=0; i<Size; i++)
    ptr[i]= Array1[i] + Array2[i];

  return ptr;
}
```

Comment: why do you need to reinvent the wheel? Simply use `std::vector` and `std::transform`

Comment: Because they want me to do it that way

Comment: who is "they" ?

Comment: the people that are "teaching" me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Granted your goal is to rewrite the `sumVec` function, you simply need to prefix your function with `template<typename T>` and replace every `int` by `T` in your function. But I would recommend keeping `int` for the index type.

```
template<typename T>
T * sumVec(T* Array1, T* Array2, int Size) {
  T *ptr = new T[Size];
  for(int i=0; i<Size; i++)
    ptr[i]= Array1[i] + Array2[i];

  return ptr;
}
```

Please note you must define your function *before* calling it, e.g. https://ideone.com/ZAyCLs